# rotate and move image to the right when hovering over another div

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, nav

I want to  hover over an image (music album) and then a record rolls out, so I want it to move to the right and to rotate a bit. It can already move to the right but I can't get it to rotate with it.

the #cover1 is the album and the #coverrecord1 is the record that needs to roll out, i like to keep it as simple as possible as i am not a pro in coding.

Many thanks.

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
     $("#cover1").hover(
         function() {
             $("#coverrecord1").stop().animate({ left: '5%' });
         },
         function() {
             $("#coverrecord1").stop().animate({ left: '0' });
         }
     );
});
```

Comment: Please post a fiddle or full snippet.

Comment: Can you add the html and css of this code as well so i can play around with it in jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y0qpwrq8/ i never used fiddle, i hope i did it correctly, only the images you need to change to something else. Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can also skip js if you wish :)

```css
.album {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 10em;
  margin: 3em auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 10em;
}
.album:after, .album:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.album:after {
  background-color: orange;
  z-index: 1;
}
.album:before {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, gray, black);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: transform 500ms;
}
.album:hover:before {
  transform: translate3d(40%, 0%, 0) rotate(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="album"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i already have pictures to use with it, the only thing that is left for it is for it to rotate.